# Test credentials for Plivo API

Tags: java, sms, plivo

Is there any option to test the API integration in the way that Twilio offers it? I mean the test credentials that don't allow to send messages to real numbers, just return the http response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing like test credentials for Plivo.